# PHP default document (index.php) displaying code as plain text in IIS7

Tags: php, iis-7, indexing, default

I've recently setup PHP 5.2.9-2 on IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008 SP2. Most everything seems to be working fine -- PHP is running great, just about all PHP code runs perfectly... EXCEPT for default pages. Any default document (index.php) is not interpreted by PHP and the page merely displays the underlying PHP code in the browser.

Best Example -- two pages (index.php + phpinfo.php) with the exact same code:
<?php phpinfo(); ?>

**http://mysite.com/test/** --> "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" (displayed in plaintext)
**http://mysite.com/test/index.php** --> "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" (displayed in plaintext)

**http://mysite.com/test/phpinfo.php** --> Proper "blue/gray" PHP Info page

What's strange is: the root of my site (http://mysite.com) interprets PHP just fine via its default document, index.php.

I've set up the site via the "best practices" (http://iis.net/fastcgi/configuration). PHP is running via FastCGI. Index.php is the only default document type. "Mysite" is housed in a subdirectory off the root drive, and IUSR has permissions throughout. Handler Mappings shows PHP via FastCGI as the top entry for *.php.

Been Googling this for hours, have seen others with very similar problems, but no resolution.

Thanks!

Comment: If you rename the index.php to something else, e.g. test.php, does it work when you access it at http://mysite.com/test/test.php ?

Comment: I noticed that someone had a similar issue [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1151168.aspx) that was caused by having moved the document root.

Comment: Yes, index.php is the same exact one-line phpinfo() call as in phpinfo.php. Name the file anything_in_the_world.php and it works. Call it "index.php", and it does not -- all PHP code is displayed in plaintext.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Turns out that if the file Default.cshtml is in the root folder, it results in a blank page. Try deleting it